# What type to use in code and database for huge file size?

Tags: c#, database-design, types

My project (`C#`) deals with many files about `1 MB ~ 2 GB` in size. `SQL server 2008` database is used. In long-term I need to do some operations over them like total sum of their size and ...

At first glance I was planned to store their size in byte (in C# code `long`, in database `BigInt`) because of file size nature and its precise. I was thinking maybe its a better idea to use a double and consider file size in MB because most of them are `1~2000 MB` and make more sense while talking about files of this project. Is there any advantage/disadvantage over these two kind of designs both in code (performance issues when there are many mathematics operations) and database (batch operations over many files) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `long`/BigInt, for a few reasons:

1. File sizes are in bytes, which are a precise discrete measure -- so you might as well use a precise discrete value.
2. If you use a decimal, it's hard to know what scale you're dealing with -- kb? bytes? mb? But if you're dealing with integers, you'll probably know that it's in bytes.
3. Not a super big deal, but performance is slightly better on most processors with longs than with decimals.
4. As far as I know, it's the conventional thing to do.

Comment: What about total sum of file size, if there are 100 million files after one year ? Doesn't it slow database after a while ?

Comment: @Steve: To some extent you can guess that something is in bytes if it's an integer, because bits and bytes are the only whole number measure of size, whereas kb, mb, gb can be decimals.

Comment: Xaqron: `double` and `long` are both 64 bits. The difference is that `long` can be calculated entirely using integer operations, whereas `double` requires floating point operations. A GPU might do floating point operations just as fast if not faster than integer operations, but a CPU generally is faster with integer operations.

Comment: Don't forget nibbles.  So an integer can be a bit, nibble, byte...  Of course byte is the most likely.

Answer (score 5):

Store the exact value in a `long`, formatting/interpreting as MB, etc should be done by the client.

Answer (score 2):

Either use `uint` or `ulong`, since:

- you can't have negative file sizes, and
- you can't have files that take fractions of bytes (e.g. 3,231.5 bytes is not a valid answer)

With a max value of 4,294,967,295 a `uint` seems the best solution for files of the size you're describing, as long as you can guarantee they'll never be any larger than this many bytes. It takes less space than a `long` or a `double`, and with only 32 bits it might even be quicker to evaluate depending on the processor and such.

Answer (score 1):

Why not [Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.maxvalue.aspx)?  `Decimal.MaxValue` has this property:

> The value of this constant is positive
>   79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335

[SQL supports this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912.aspx) for most of the .Net valid range.  Limitations in conversion are noted [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2010/08/31/when-does-sql-server-decimal-not-convert-to-net-decimal.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If i remember correctly, file size is already returned as a long in .Net. Also, floats are 64bit and longs are 64bit, but floats are slower.

Also, if you do calculations are doubles, you will have to convert a long to a double on every file, while if you wait until the end, then there's only one conversion.

Do all of your calculations as bytes, then at the last step you can convert to a float to report something like 2.051GB or whatever.